# What does the server receive when a client connects with HTTP protocol?

Tags: python, python-2.7, http, get

As far as I understand if I connect to a server using the HTTP protocol the server itself receives only the application layer (and the computer deals with the other layers containing the protocol, ip etc.)

With that in mind, I'm trying to check if the request my server receives is a GET request and if it's in the 1.1 version of the HTTP protocol. here is the code:

```
request = Client.recv(4096)

#Check if it's a valid HTTP request and get the path

isntHTTP = True
counter = 0
path = ''
for letter in range(0, len(request)-1):
    if request[letter] == ' ':
        counter += 1
    if counter == 2:
        if request[letter+1:letter+14] == 'HTTP/1.1\\r\\n':
            isntHTTP = False
        break
    if counter == 1:
        path += request[letter]
if request[:3] != 'GET' or isntHTTP:
    #send code 500 (add later)
    Client.close()
    continue
```

For some reason this code always closes the client and continues. The all thing is inside a while loop so the 'continue' command isn't the problem.

Comment: You need to explain what `request` is.

Comment: Instead of looping letter by letter, consider using `request.split()` to split the input into lines and then split the lines into words.

Comment: You shouldn't escape the backslashes in `HTTP/1.1\\r\\n`. That makes it look for literal backslashes in the request, but the request actually contains return and newline.

Comment: Don't waste your time, create any socket with python(port > 1024), open a browser type your IP and port , check what is http request contents(GET). Use a form post to your server see which pattern used this method(POST).